# Why does TransformedCollection not implement hashCode?

Tags: java, collections, guava

I expect two identical transforms to result objects that have the same `hashCode`. I'd like to use this property to check whether my object has changed in a meaningful way.

Unfortunately, Guava's `TransformedCollection extends AbstractCollection` which (unlike `AbstractList`) does not implement `hashCode` or equals, and `TransformedCollection` does no such attempt itself.

- Could we not calculate a `hashCode` based on the values as returned by the iterator's order or some such?
- Or would that still not guarantee identical `hashCodes`?
- Perhaps we can solve this problem for `TransformedCollection` in a way it cannot be solved for `AbstractCollection`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no sane way for defining `Collection.hashCode`. A collection can be a `Set` or a `List` (or something else) and the two define `hashCode` in an incompatible way.

Moreover, for the same reason there's no sane definition for  `transformedCollection1.equals(transformedCollection2)`. It could either ignore the order, or not (Set or List semantics). Even worse, the returned `Collection` is just a view, and such `equals` would be terrible inefficient.

I'd suggest to use something like `ImmutableList.copyOf(transformedCollection)` and work with it.

Comment: Or if you have a `List`, use `Lists.transform`.